# Highlight/select current item in numbered list in MS Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I often type up procedures in MS Word using a numbered list.  I'm looking for a way to quickly move between items so I can very quickly select the item that I am on.  I realize I can select the entire region with my mouse and that would accomplish the idea of what I'm looking for, but I wonder if there is a much faster way?  For example, the text for number 6 is selected/highlighed, I do number 6, I push a few keys on the keyboard and voila, number 7 is selected/highlighted.

Is such a thing built-in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built function but you can record a very simple macro to sequentially go down your numbered list. Consider the tasks you want to do. You want to quickly run down your list, move your cursor to the end of each line, and highlight ALL text to the beginning of that line. A macro just stores all these instructions so that you don't have to do them yourself each time. Follow these steps:

1. Keep your cursor at the start of a list item (no highlight)
2. Go to View > Macros > Record Macro
3. In the Window that pops up, type in a macro name and select 'Keyboard'
   [image: keyboard]
4. Enter a new shortcut key by **pressing the actual shortcut you want** (say <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>). This shortcut is safe and won't overlap with any existing Word 2007 shortcuts. 
   [image: assign]
5. Click 'Assign' and close the window.
6. The mouse pointer will also have changed to be a pointer with a tape next to it to show
   you are recording a macro. Only **keyboard** operations are permitted. Press the down arrow (to go to the next line), press <kbd>end</kbd> to navigate to the end of line, and then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+left arrow to highlight the entire line.
7. Go to View > Macros > Stop Recording. The macro should be saved as is.

To test it, place the cursor anywhere in the numbered list field and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>. You should be able to repeatedly jump to the next item in the list and have the entire line fully highlighted each time.

You can create a similar macro (with another shortcut) for navigating *upwards* in the list the same way. Easy enough, I hope.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want but it's a lot closer than what I currently have at my disposal.  Thanks for your help.  I have already set up the macros and they work well.